# Bash - finding substrings in string

Tags: bash

I am new to bash. I have experience in java and python but no experience in bash so I'm struggling with the simplest of tasks.

What I want to achieve is I want to look through the string and find certain sub strings, numbers to be exact. But not all numbers just number that are followed by " xyz". For example:

`string="Blah blah boom boom 14 xyz foo bar 12 foo boom 55 XyZ hue hue 15 xyzlkj 45hh."`

And I want to find numbers:
`14` `55` and `15`

How would I go about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `grep` with lookahead

```
echo "$string" | grep -i -P -o '[0-9]+(?= xyz)'
```

Explanation:

- `-i` – ignore case
- `-P` – interpret pattern as a Perl regular expression
- `-o` – print only matching
- `[0-9]+(?= xyz)` – match one or more numbers followed by `xyz`

For more information see:

- https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep
- http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html
- https://github.com/tldr-pages/tldr/blob/master/pages/common/grep.md

Comment: I will take this one because it is explained better and provides some additional references. Thank you good sir.

Comment: Hi, i just have a follow up question. I want to add those numbers up and just print out the sum but I'm not sure how to do that. I tried: $result=expr $result + ${"$line" | grep -i -P -o '[0-9]+(?= xyz)'} and I get a ${"$line" | grep -i -P -o '[0-9]+(?= lešnik)'}: bad substitution

Comment: Hi, first declare result sum – `declare -i sum`, then foreach results and add each result to sum – `for num in $(echo "$string" | grep -i -P -o '[0-9]+(?= xyz)'); do sum+=$num; done`

Comment: That did it for me tyvm.

Answer (score 0):

***grep*** + ***cut*** approach (without *PCRE*):

```
echo $string | grep -io '[0-9]* xyz' | cut -d ' ' -f1
```

The output:

```
14
55
15
```